# Bootstrap navigation Hovered or Clicked

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make the navigation buttons change color when hovered or clicked. But the problem is, whatever I do, I can't seem to make it work. 
The bootstrap navigation is different from CSS and I have no idea where I'm making a mistake.

Here is my code, and any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

```
HTML:

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li><a href="index.html" >HOME</a></li>
  <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
  <li><a href="resume.html">RESUME</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  </nav>
```

and this is my CSS:

```
.container-fluid{
margin-left: 30em;
}

.navbar-brand{
max-width:100px;
padding-left: 10px;
}

.navbar-default {
background-color: #f8f8f800; 
border-color: #e7e7e700;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
color: #faebd7;
}

.navbar-nav>li>a {
padding-top: 40px;
padding-bottom: 15px;
font-size: 1.8em;
font-weight: bold;    
}
```

Comment: You haven't declared any color for hover or any active states.

Answer (score 0):

As the comment showed, you had no `:hover` class stated.You cannot have a color change without putting a hover on the element.

Here this code has been tested and works for your desired effect:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li><a class="link" href="index.html" >HOME</a></li>
  <li><a class="link" href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
  <li><a class="link" href="resume.html">RESUME</a></li>
  <li><a class="link" href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  </nav>
```

CSS:

```
 .container-fluid{
    margin-left: 5em;
    }

    .navbar-brand{
    max-width:100px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    }

    .navbar-default {
    background-color: #f8f8f800; 
    border-color: #e7e7e700;
    }

    /** For simplicity of the example I added a class to your link tag. See the hover effect below **/

    .link {

      color: #faebd7;
      transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; 
    }

    .link:hover {

      color: red; 

    }

    .navbar-nav>li>a {

    font-size: 1.8em;
    font-weight: bold;    
    }
```

See for yourself: https://jsfiddle.net/billy_farroll/hnff1xw1/